# Is there an easier way to find if a string is **not** null or empty?

Tags: c#, code-behind

So I've got this block of code:

```
string BizID = DT1["Business_ID"].ToString();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(BizID))
{
}
else
{
   DDLBustype.SelectedValue = BizID;
}
```

Seems like there should be an easier way to do this.  Maybe I'm just having a brain f*rt but shouldn't there be a way to do this without having to use "else"?

Comment: `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BizID)) { DDLBustype.SelectedValue = BizID; }`

Comment: If `DT1["Business_ID"]` is null, calling .ToString() on it will raise a null reference exception.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot - why not post that as the answer?

Comment: Sweet Jesus, I need coffee...  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Adding answers from comments as community wiki so the question can be closed.

```
string BizID = DT1["Business_ID"]?.ToString(); // add null conditional operator in case it is null.
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BizID))
{
   DDLBustype.SelectedValue = BizID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually hide this in an extension method for *string* call it HasValue() so it is similar to what Nullable types have. Then my code looks cleaner, like:

```
if(firstName.HasValue())
    // ...
```